# I would like to display the time statically on a UILabel when the view is loaded

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilabel

That's the short story.

I have a nib with 6 UILabels for 6 different times.

The goal:

1. UILabel1 - calculate 90 minutes from current time
2. UILabel2 - 90 minutes from UILabel1 (or just 180 minutes from current time)
3. repeat, etc...

I can currently display the current times but I'm not sure how to calculate the times I need (see above).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString *currentTime1 = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
NSString *currentTime2 = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
NSString *currentTime3 = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
NSString *currentTime4 = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
NSString *currentTime5 = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
NSString *currentTime6 = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];

timeLabel1.text = currentTime1;
timeLabel2.text = currentTime2;
timeLabel3.text = currentTime3;
timeLabel4.text = currentTime4;
timeLabel5.text = currentTime5;
timeLabel6.text = currentTime6;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

sidenote:I have found this to be a such a great place to find answers over the last 2 years!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Date with 90 minutes from current time

```
NSDate *nextDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*90];
```

Then

```
NSString *currentTime2 = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextDate ];
timeLabel2.text = currentTime2;
```

Comment: This works. Can you check to see if I got this right, @beryllium?
    NSDate *nextDate1 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*104];
    NSDate *nextDate2 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*194];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    NSString *currentTime1 = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextDate1];
    NSString *currentTime2 = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextDate2];
    timeLabel1.text = currentTime1;
    timeLabel2.text = currentTime2;

Comment: edited for clarity - is this the best way to do this for all 6 labels?

    NSDate *nextDate1 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*104];
    NSDate *nextDate2 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*194];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    NSString *currentTime1 = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextDate1];
    NSString *currentTime2 = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextDate2];
    timeLabel1.text = currentTime1;
    timeLabel2.text = currentTime2;

Comment: Looks good, but i would recommend to make a cycle, on each step add 90.

Answer (score 0):

NSDate has the class method [dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDate/dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow%3a) for this.